# What is the earliest point a passenger arriving from outside of the EU and from the UK can meet up at Schiphol (Amsterdam) airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, netherlands, ams

After a long trip for studies I'll finally be going home next Friday. My partner went on a trip of his own while I was away. Our flights will be arriving about 15 minutes from each other (well, that's the plan), and we're very exited about seeing each other again. He'll be arriving at gate H from the UK. I don't know what gate I will be arriving yet. It is Friday 29th of April's KL896 from Pudong, China.

What is the earliest point we can meet up? Do we arrive in areas separated by checks or can we just hop off the plane and walk to each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coming off the planes you come in the same halls as those going to the planes use.
All of the airside that is 'non Schengen' is connected, if by a long(ish) walkway.
That means that the first to arrive can go to the gate used by the second to arrive and meet there.
Although at most of the airside space is open, there might be some parts of the airport still locked off by security for the whole of the area.
In that case you will be able to meet just outside of the security check for the area of the airport.

Arriving plane gates are not announced so you will have to have your phones at the ready, call as soon as the gate is known. And sometimes passengers are bussed into the airport and might arrive at a door very close to passport control.

If you ask your flight attendants, it is likely that they can include the information in the 'welcome to Amsterdam' message, but otherwise you can see it on the outside of the airport buildings as well as on the signs within the halls as soon as you come into the buildings.

Remember that you might have to go to different locations of the airport to collect your luggage.
You do not need to use a particular part of passport control, and you are free to walk from one set of luggage carousels to the other set, and you are allowed to pass out of the secure zone at any of the exits.

Both of your flights are from outside the Schengen area.
If either of you had come from within the Schengen area, you would earliest be able to meet at the luggage carousels.

This answer is from personal experience, having used Schiphol many times, for within Schengen as well as for out of Schengen flights.
And I have met my friend in luggage reclaim on some airports myself.

If you have people meeting you outside the secure zone, you might need to call them which exit you use (based on which luggage you collect last) or arrange to meet them at a set point in the airport.

Edit:
Based on the answer by @EcD, the area at the top of the stairs/lifts to passport control, on the side of the airport where the flight from China is using the gate, is the most likely point.
But I am not sure as I never arrived from a 'non clean' area. Luggage reclaim will certainly be possible, as those are for all flights in two huge halls.

Comment: Are non-Schengen departures and arrivals not segregated in Schipol (like in the US, but contrary to most other international airports I'm aware of)? That means you can transfer from one non-Schengen flight to another without going through security?

Comment: Such a detailed answer, thank you! I especially like the comment about asking the flight attendants, will certainly do that.

Comment: That reminded me, some parts of the airport still have security points for a bigger area. Some flights have extra security near the gate. I do not like the 'security at the start of the secure area' myself. I feel much better when security is done for much smaller numbers of flights, best per flight.

Comment: Certain American airports would drive you nuts, then, where you can go to any terminal and any gate after clearing security.

Comment: Not drive me nuts, it is just now what I prefer.

Comment: I thought that the top level for D gates used to be for some non-Schengen EU flights flights where passport control was at the top of the stairs.  I don't recall this being connected with the rest of the non-Schengen international space.  Maybe this has changed or I am misremembering.

Comment: You misremember. The pier used for the Schengen flights has a wall in the middle, when you get off a flight you are either sluiced into the one half or into the other.  All on the higher floor. The lower floor is used for departure 'holding' areas by the cheap airlines as well as for practical spaces.

Comment: It ended up being mostly as you said. It would have been possible for me to go through security and go to my parter's flight, but my flight ended up getting delayed and that sounded like a lot of hassle, so we met up at the luggage carousels, just past passport control.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that since the central security changes last year, Willeke's answer is most likely incorrect for you (although as I've not been on an inbound flight from an "insecure" country since June 2015, when this all changed, I am happy to be corrected by someone with first-hand experience).

Schiphol airport describes the changes [in detail](https://www.schiphol.nl/Travellers/News/GreaterComfortAsAResultOfCentralSecurity1.htm), but in summary:

- Departing passengers are now screened before entering the departure lounges at all, immediately after checkin. Similar to most airports.
- Arriving passengers from "clean" non-Schengen countries (such as the UK and US), that meet EU security standards, are deposited directly into this shared departure area. This hasn't changed, but it does now make transfers easier for them, no need to re-clear security at the gate. They leave by heading towards passport control.
- Arriving passengers from countries that don't meet EU security standards, and I strongly suspect this includes China, are shepherded along separate corridors on a separate level directly to passport control, and avoiding the clean passengers.

So - your partner should arrive into the main departure area. You should be herded directly to passport control. You could meet up before passport control therefore, or at the baggage claim. It's unlikely that you'll be able to get into the clean departure area without a boarding pass - although you could try, perhaps they won't check. It's unlikely your partner will be easily able to make it backwards along the unclean arriving passenger route - although again, that may be possible.

Comment: I did include that some areas are still not in the general part of the 'all security at the main entrance to the secure area' but I have noticed that a lot of flights do not leave from the areas you would expect them to, arriving flights is even more of a guess.

Comment: I think if they were both coming from clean countries, or both from unclean countries, it would be easier. I think it's just an unfortunate pair of countries (I was going to add it as a comment, but it got a bit long :) )

Comment: I think I would wait at the point where the people from the one section will meet those from the other section, if you can not go on for all the way. I assumed planes from China would arrive in the main area, but you might be right that they are in the smaller area with separate security.

Comment: Wow that's confusing. I think we'll aim for the plaza unless I catch wifi first as I lost my Dutch sim. Hurray for small technology.

Comment: Let us know how you get on!

Comment: Unclean passengers are able to transit without going through passport control, are they not? Yes—they have to pass through security, but only those connecting to Schengen flights pass through passport control.

Comment: That's correct - they go through security to transit, or they go through passport control to exit (or both, as you say, to transit to Schengen).

Comment: @EdC will certainly do. I'll post an update (and accept most helpful answer) when I get home.